# Save copied data to different excel files

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to save different parts of copied data from one excel file, to the correspond new excel file, but I'm getting everything on one new file.

What am I doing wrong?

For example, in the picture I want to have 4 new excel files, with the names AAA, BBB, CCC and DDD.
The separation is every time a blank row appears.
The data to be copied will be from that row until the next blank row. (all columns)

[image]

Thanks

```
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(xref_file)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

for row in range(1,ws1.max_row):
    if(ws1.cell(row,1).value is None):   
        
        wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook() 
        ws2 = wb2.active
     
        conveyor_name = ws1["A1"].value
        conveyor_name.split(' -')
        conveyor_name = conveyor_name.split(' -')[0]
        filename = conveyor_name + ".xlsx"
        destination_file = os.path.join(destination,filename)
        wb2.save(destination_file) 
    
        # copying the cell values from source 
        # excel file to destination excel file
        for i in range (1, mr+1):
            for j in range (1, mc+1):
                # reading cell value from source excel file
                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
            
                # writing the read value to destination excel file
                ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value

        wb2.save(destination_file)  

ws1.delete_rows(1,mr)
    
wb1.save(xref_file)
```

Comment: You are creating a new Excel workbook inside the `for` loop, with your command `wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()`. You then determine the filename from cell `A1`. You copy some values from `wb1` and those seem to be overwritten on every loop. Please note that some variables like `mr` and `mc` are undefined in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 1:
The changes that I have made to your code are that I have additional conditions which check whether an empty row is present or not, if it is an empty row then it will set the new_sheet variable to true. If it is not empty and if new_sheet is true then a new sheet is created, else a loop starts which copies the content to the new sheet.
Hence the updated code should be as follows:

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(destination + "/" + xref_file)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

new_sheet = True
# for row in range(1,ws1.max_row):
row = 1
while row < ws1.max_row:
    if(ws1.cell(row,1).value is not None):  
        if new_sheet == True:
            wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook() 
            ws2 = wb2.active
            conveyor_name = ws1["A" + str(row)].value
            conveyor_name = conveyor_name.split()[0]
            filename = conveyor_name + ".xlsx"
            destination_file = os.path.join(destination,filename)
            print(destination_file)
            wb2.save(destination_file) 
            new_sheet = False
            row = row + 1
        else:
            # copying the cell values from source 
            # excel file to destination excel file
            for i in range (row, mr+1):
                if ws1.cell(i,1).value is None:
                    break
                for j in range (1, mc+1):
                    # reading cell value from source excel file
                    c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
                
                    # writing the read value to destination excel file
                    ws2.cell(row = i - row + 1, column = j).value = c.value
            row = i
            wb2.save(destination_file)
    else:
        new_sheet = True
        row = row + 1
```

Edit 0: There are several optimizations and errors that can be observed. Since I don't know the nature of the data in excel sheet, some of these may not apply to you

> ```
> wb1 = xl.load_workbook(xref_file) ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0] 
> mr = ws1.max_row 
> mc = ws1.max_column
> for row in range(1,ws1.max_row):
>     if(ws1.cell(row,1).value is None):
>         wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook() 
>         ws2 = wb2.active
> ```

1. If the above If condition is true then there shouldn't be any value in A1. Further, if there should be a value in A1 then you may want to check the values from the second row to pass the if condition, hence row should have values starting from 2 to ws1.max_row

> ```
>         conveyor_name = ws1["A1"].value
> ```

3. This below line doesn't make much sense because you are again using the same value in the line after that

> ```
>         conveyor_name.split(' -') # this is not required
>         conveyor_name = conveyor_name.split(' -')[0]
>         filename = conveyor_name + ".xlsx"
>         destination_file = os.path.join(destination,filename)
>         wb2.save(destination_file) 
>
> # copying the cell values from source 
>
> # excel file to destination excel file
> for i in range (1, mr+1):
>     for j in range (1, mc+1):
>         # reading cell value from source excel file
>         c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
>     
>         # writing the read value to destination excel file
>         ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
>
> wb2.save(destination_file)  
>
> ws1.delete_rows(1,mr) wb1.save(xref_file)
> ```

Comment: this way I'm only getting one excel file, and I want one excel per "table" that is on my original file. ( I edit the question so it becomes more clearer).

Comment: You can find the updated code based on your screenshot